# Creating an image with PHP with data from <form> and output as <img src> (GD)

Tags: php, html, post, gd

I have this project where the user can customize how their avatar looks based on skin color and hair color.

In order to get the data from the user, I use an html form:

Index.php:

```html
<p>Choose your hair colour:</p>
<form method="post" action="generate.php">
 <input type="radio" name="hair" value="blonde">Blonde
 <input type="radio" name="hair" value="brown">Brown
 <input type="radio" name="hair" value="black">Black
 <input type="radio" name="hair" value="red">Red

<p>Choose your skin color:</p>
 <input type="radio" name="skin" value="pale">White
 <input type="radio" name="skin" value="tan">White(Tanned)
 <input type="radio" name="skin" value="asian">Asian
 <input type="radio" name="skin" value="brown">Brown
 <input type="radio" name="skin" value="black">Black
 <p><input style="border-style: solid;"type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submitBtn"></p>
</form>

<img src="generate.php" alt="" />
```

And this is the generate.php file:

```js
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
{
 $haircolor = $_POST['hair'];
 $skincolor = $_POST['skin'];
 
 //Hair color assignment of variables
 if($haircolor == "blonde")
 {
  $h_r = 150;
  $h_g = 0;
  $h_b = -150;
  $h_op = 0;  
 }
 elseif($haircolor == "brown")
 {
  $h_r = -110;
  $h_g = -140;
  $h_b = -150;
  $h_op = 0;
 }
 elseif($haircolor == "black")
 {
  $h_r = -170;
  $h_g = -170;
  $h_b = -170;
  $h_op = 0;
 }
 elseif($haircolor == "red")
 {
  $h_r = 150;
  $h_g = -140;
  $h_b = -170;
  $h_op = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Please choose correct values (make sure you didn't miss anything)!";
 }




 //Skin Color assignment of variables
 if($skincolor == "pale")
 {
  $s_r = 50;
  $s_g = -2;
  $s_b = -10;
  $s_op = 0;  
 }
 elseif($skincolor == "tan")
 {
  $s_r = 70;
  $s_g = -30;
  $s_b = -55;
  $s_op = 0;
 }
 elseif($skincolor == "asian")
 {
  $s_r = 70;
  $s_g = -25;
  $s_b = -85;
  $s_op = 0;
 }
 elseif($skincolor == "brown")
 {
  $s_r = -50;
  $s_g = -120;
  $s_b = -250;
  $s_op = 0;
 }
 elseif($skincolor == "black")
 {
  $s_r = -135;
  $s_g = -180;
  $s_b = -205;
  $s_op = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  echo "Please choose correct values (make sure you didn't miss anything)!";
 }




//Creating the image
header ("Content-type: image/png");

$source = imagecreatefrompng("images/hair.png");
$source2 = imagecreatefrompng("images/line.png");
$source3 = imagecreatefrompng("images/clothing.png");

$destination = imagecreatefrompng("images/skin.png"); 

imagealphablending($source, true);
imagesavealpha($source, true);


$largeur_source = imagesx($source);
$hauteur_source = imagesy($source);

$largeur_source2 = imagesx($source2);
$hauteur_source2 = imagesy($source2);

$largeur_source3 = imagesx($source3);
$hauteur_source3 = imagesy($source3);

$largeur_destination = imagesx($destination);
$hauteur_destination = imagesy($destination);

imagefilter($destination, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $s_r, $s_g, $s_b, $s_op);
imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $h_r, $h_g, $h_b, $h_op);
imagefilter($source3, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilter($source2, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 0, 0, 0, 0);


imagecopy($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_source, $hauteur_source);
imagecopy($destination, $source2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_source2, $hauteur_source2);
imagecopy($destination, $source3, 0, 0, 0, 0, $largeur_source3, $hauteur_source3);

imagepng($destination);

 
}


?>
```

The image generation itself works perfectly, but it generates it on a whole other page (www.mysite.com/generate.php).

How do I make it so that it generates itself on index.php? I've added 
 in index.php but it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to submit the form data using an ajax request so that you do not get a full page reload. You can inject whatever result you receive as a response to the ajax call into the already loaded html document. All that is client side logic, so javascript. It has nothing to do with php from that point of view.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do it?

Comment: You will find many many existing examples for an ajax submission of a html form to a php script. About handling the response: you could send the image base64 encoded and inject it as such into the image tag.

Comment: Another, maybe even easier alternative is to catch the form submission with a client side handler (again javascript, no way around that) and change the image src url in the loaded page. That allows to easily replace the loaded image in the loaded page. That would mean you use a http GET request for the avatar image instead of the current post. You just have to compile the form elements into a GET url pointing to your generate.php script, that's it...

Comment: I think I'm going to go with your second solution. I'll see if it works!